# What type of image path should I store in the DataBase (PHP/MySQL)

Tags: php, database, image, path, store

What type of image path should I store in the DataBase - relative or absolute? I have encountered a problem with relative paths, when images need to be displayed from different pages - those relative paths **from the database** doesn't work on some pages...

So, I've tried to use absolute pahts (to store them in the database), for example something like

```
save_image(__DIR__.'/../images/');
```

But the problem is that those absolute pahts (with **__DIR__**) cannot be used to display images (because they look something like:

```
c:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\public\admin/../images/picture.jpg).
```

**Or, maybe it's a bad idea to store image paths in the DataBase?**

Comment: Solution: Dynamic absolute paths! Store path relative to somewhere. Create absolute path when accessing. On a side note, remember that local paths and URL's are different.

Comment: I would only store the filename and build the paths accordingly.